# Printing code with syntax highlighting?

Tags: printing, language-agnostic, code-formatting

I have occasion to need to print code (Horrors!!! ;) ), and i was wondering what editor or tool would i use to print that code out with proper formatting and syntax highlighting? If it's important, it will be c# code but ideally the tool will work for as many languages as possible. Can Notepad++ or something handle this?

Comment: This superuser question has several suggestions, including one for Notepad++: http://superuser.com/questions/39571/how-do-i-easily-highlight-the-syntax-of-php-code-in-word

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, Notepad++ can certainly print code with syntax highlighting.

Colour printing would obviously be preferable, but on the occasions when I've printed in black and white, the subtle differences in colour [rendered as shades of grey, of course] can be difficult to distinguish.

However, I think a little customisation of the colour schemes should make this less of a problem.

Answer (score 41):

You can use [Vim](https://www.vim.org/)! It's probably installed already if you're on modern Linux/MacOS and an easy install if not.

`:syntax` will turn syntax highlighting on and `:hardcopy` will print it. There's [syntax highlighting definitions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#syntax) for many languages out there. The default look is usually optimised for screen display, but you can [fix](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Printing_with_syntax_highlighting_independent_of_your_normal_highlighting) [that](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip284).

Simply open the file on command line with `vim <filename>`, type `:syntax on<ENTER>`, then `:hardcopy<ENTER>` to print it. Quit Vim with `:q!<ENTER>`.

There's also the `:TOhtml` command which will open the current selection as HTML in a new Vim window. Capture the entire document with `:%y<ENTER>` followed by `:TOhtml<ENTER>` to open it.

Comment: @RCIX Don't say sorry--we're sorry for you!

Comment: You could also issue `:TOhtml` command which converts source code into HTML file with colors and everything.

Comment: I prefer to preview the results before printing.  You can print to a .ps file via `:hardcopy > %.ps`   If you want a pdf file instead, use ps2pdf: `hardcopy > %.ps  | !ps2pdf %.ps && rm %.ps`  To edit the font: `set printfont=Courier:h8`

Comment: to add line numbers in the printed files run `set printoptions=number:y`

Answer (score 15):

**New Answer:**

Use TextMate. It prints colored code automatically. There's no setup. Just print. In case previous or newer versions can't do this I'm using TextMate version 2.0.23

**Old Answer, and the answer for people who don't have Macs:**

Use vim. Its the easiest method to do it in my experience by far, that is, once you know how.

Vim comes pre-installed on Macs, btw. And I know how you special people like colors, so I'm going to make this impatientbusinessman-proof for the benefit of all.

1.) open file

> vim filename.m

2.) enable syntax coloration (mine did not have enabled by default)

> :syntax on

3.) print

```
:hardcopy
```

Vim will choose your system's default printer without asking you so make sure you set that up first.

4.) exit the program (this is actually not a given)

```
:q
```

Answer (score 8):

http://pygments.org/ is one option. It supports a *ton* of languages, and since it's written as a python library, you can script the conversion process however you want.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio will, and allows you have a completely separate configuration for printing.

Comment: Where? I can only print in B/W

Comment: I cannot recall, but based on the age of the answer I would have been referring to Visual Studio *2008* which had native support for colour printing. VS2010 and VS2012 can use the [Color Printing](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/00ec88c2-1553-47d2-8170-3c5baa0c6e44)[sic] extension. There does not seem to be an equivalent for VS2013.

Answer (score 3):

I recently compared the 2 solutions already mentioned : `vim` & `pygments`. They both give great results, but there is how you can practically use them quickly:

- `pygments` does not provide direct export to PDF. Hence, the simplest solution I found was to export to HTML and then use `wkhtmltopdf`. You can combine both operations using the following bash script:

```sh
src2pdf () {
    local noext="${1%.*}"
    pygmentize -O full -o "$noext.html" "$1"
    # enabling line wrapping in <pre> blocks
    perl -i -wpe '/<style.*>$/&&($_.="pre{white-space:pre-wrap;}\n")' "$noext.html"
    wkhtmltopdf "$noext.html" "$noext.pdf"
    rm "$noext.html"
}
```

- for `vim`, it's as simple as this: `TERM=xterm-256color vim '+hardcopy >out.ps' +q code.src`
  I found out that the `$TERM` environment variable can affect the output colors, so I prefer to set it explicitly.
  And finally, you may need to tweak your *.vimrc* a little:

```
set printfont=:h9  
set printoptions=number:y,left:5pc
```

Answer (score 3):

The tool called `enscript` is very much the tool for doing this.  It is very powerful, is not tied to an editor nor a language and you can create PDF's with syntax highlighting.

The documentation pretty much says it all.

[enscript man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enscript)

Answer (score 1):

Under unix you might want to try a2ps. It is flexible and produces nice results.

Answer (score 1):

I while ago I created a household [python script](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576812-generate-html-syntax-highlighted-listings-for-any-/?in=user-4170754) that wraps pygments into a small console utility. It works with any language supported by [pygments](http://pygments.org/languages/).

Also if you happen to use eclipse, you could simply copy the selected text in the editor and then paste it in a RTF-aware editor like MS Word - it will preserve all the colors, fonts and formatting.

Comment: haven't tested it, sounds nice, hope it works ok :) however, in case of more batch-oriented printing (for larger number of files) I'm still interested in some HTML-to-printer tool that could be used as a companion?

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with **Visual Studio 2012** concerning the highlighted printing an handeling the described problem:

- Download and install this [Power Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) which implements the color
  printing, besides some other features and bug fixes. Works for me!

Answer (score 1):

## Solution For Bash Shell

1. Add this line to `~/.bashrc` if you are using UBUNTU
   or, to `~/.bash_profile` if you are using MAC
   If that file does not exists, create it.

   alias lprc='vim -me -c ":syntax on" -c ":hardcopy" -c ":q"'
2. `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile`
3. To print colored hello.py just do this:
   `lprc hello.py`   instead of `lpr hello.py`

Answer (score 1):

Use **ConTEXT** programming editor (which is free). I am using it for both generating .pdf-s with syntax highlighted source code and printing to paper.

There are many [ConTEXT syntax highlihting definitions to download](http://www.contexteditor.org/highlighters/) and you can make your own highligher file which will BTW be highlighted using the **ConTEXT Highlighter Files highlighter** definition.

Answer (score 0):

I do it downloading js and css files from

https://prismjs.com/

There are so many 5-7 options to select the theme and language highlighter. Once you select a theme and download the tiny js/css files the next thing you need to do is rename the code file to html, and call the css/js files. Open the html in a browser and print it. Done!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this in case you've to print with bnw syntax highlighting https://github.com/SGI-CAPP-AT2/code-highlight-n-print